_freeze_and_vec field in gymnasium.Env
I am looking at codes mentioning
env._freeze_and_vec = False/True. What does it do exactly? In which file of gymnasium can I find this field?
I tried looking at all the files with grep -r "_freeze_and_vec" in the gymnasium repository. However it failed as there is no such field.

Are you sure that _freeze_and_vec attribute is from Gymnasium? Also, it would be more helpful if you upload more of relevant codes.
